# IIS rewrite rule one query parameter with multiple values

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting, query-string

IIS web.config:

I am trying to redirect a path like

mysite.com/?myparam=123,321,112
to
mysite.com/mypage?param=123,321,112

```
 <rule name="Multiple QueryValue String Rewrite" enabled="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="myparam=(.\,)" />            
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="/mypage?param={C:0}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
```

But whatever i try, it will only forwards the first param. leading to
/mypage?param=123

I have tried multiple combination of {C} and pattern regex.

Comment: Did you try `pattern="myparam=(.*)"`? Or `pattern="myparam=([0-9,]*)"`

Comment: Both resulting in 
/mypage?param=123

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew, sorry.. your answer was correct. (.*)
This was a browser caching issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IMPORTANT: before try something new remember ALWAYS to clear the cache of browser! it's mandatory.**

Now...

1. the **pattern** you use is not correct, you have to use one suggested by Wiktor Stribiżew

So using `pattern="myparam=([0-9\,]*)` with `url="/mypage?param={C:1}"` try this:

> ```
>  <rule name="Multiple QueryValue String Rewrite" enabled="true">
>           <match url="(.*)" />
>           <conditions>
>             <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="myparam=([0-9\,]*)" />            
>           </conditions>
>           <action type="Redirect" url="/mypage?param={C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
>  </rule>
> ```

If that is not correct there is something wrong in "," character... something about encoding?

if you try this one what happened?:

> ```
>  <rule name="Multiple QueryValue String Rewrite" enabled="true">
>           <match url="(.*)" />
>           <conditions>
>             <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="myparam=([0-9]*)\,([0-9]*)\,([0-9]*)" />            
>           </conditions>
>           <action type="Redirect" url="/mypage?param={C:1},{C:2},{C:3}" appendQueryString="false" />
>  </rule>
> ```

Comment: Thank you, this was a browser caching issue :)

Answer (score 0):

If only for **mysite.com/?myparam=123,321,112**, you can try the following URL rewriting rules:

```
 <rule name="Multiple QueryValue String Rewrite" enabled="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="myparam=(.*)" />            
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="/mypage?param={C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this was a browser caching issue :)  As ValB said.